# Javascript ondrag, ondragstart, ondragend

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I've been trying to use `ondrag()` and some other functions on a `div` rendered dynamically on an `HTML` page.

None of these events seem to fire, nor do I get any errors.  I can't find much helpful documentation on it either.  Am I interpreting it wrongly, can you use these events to script functionality to drag a div around the screen?

Comment: are you using any javascript frameworks/plugins? If not other than IE and safari other browsers dont understand ondrag. can you paste your code?

Comment: Borwser? doctype? May you give some other details?

Comment: Good article: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html

Comment: The HTML5 spec standardizes drag-and-drop: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#dnd

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop

Note: It does not work in every browser.

If you want a cross-browser support use jQuery: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

jQuery example:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
            drag: function(event, ui) {}
        });
    });
</script>
```

Another example:

```
<div id="toBeDragged" draggable="true">
  This text <strong>may</strong> be dragged.
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('toBeDragged').addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'This text may be dragged');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not using JQuery sorry

Comment: @Tom Gullen: what about the other example?

Comment: If you want a robust cross-browser dragging solution, I would recommend using one of the many available options built on an existing JS framework.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used drag myself much but I believe it's the drag "edit action" - eg selecting text and dragging it within a textbox/textarea.

You may need to implement your own `onmousedown()` `onmouseup()` and `onmousemove()` handlers for the functionality I think you're after

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `<div>`-s are not draggable by default, unlike `<a>-s`. You must add **draggable=true**:

```
<div draggable=true ondragstart=...>HTML</div>
```

Works on Firefox 75 like that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there content in the div? I don't think it's the element itself that gets dragged in this particular event.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to do this is with jQuery UI, make sure you use it after your dynamic `div` has been rendered.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my_draggable_elements').draggable({
        drag: function(){
          // do something
        }
    });
});
```