# .ondragstart not equivalent to .addEventListener("dragstart"

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, firefox-addon, dom-events

I want to make an img element unselectable and undraggable because I'm using it as a window resizing control (clicking and dragging on the surrounding div resizes a window).

It works perfectly fine as the following:

```
noSelect[x].ondragstart = function() {return false};
```

But since this will be used in a firefox(3.6.*) extension which uses an XPCNativeWrapper around every HTMLElement, I cannot use ".onsdragstart" and have to use ".addEventListener"

The problem is the equivalent to the above code isn't working. Clicking and dragging the img triggers firefox's default image dragging, instead of resizing my window in the following:

```
noSelect[x].addEventListener("dragstart", function () {return false}, false)
```

Are the two lines of code quoted above not equivalent?

Full context for unselectable objects:

```
var noSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("noSelect")
    for (x in noSelect) {
        if (x == "length")
            break
        noSelect[x].unselectable = "on";
        noSelect[x].onselectstart = function(){return false};
        noSelect[x].ondragstart = function() {return false};
        noSelect[x].style.userSelect = "none"; // w3c standard
        noSelect[x].style.MozUserSelect = "none"; // Firefox
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

addEventListener registers an [EventListener](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener), which doesn't have any special return code treatment.

Returning false from most `on*` event handlers [cancels the event per the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm), in regular EventListener this is achieved by calling `event.preventDefault()` as Neil mentioned in his answer.

Comment: This is the answer I'd like to accept, but this project was from a while ago and I'd like to go back and verify it first.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why `function() { return false; }` doesn't work, but I do know that `function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }` will work in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

1. ondragstart is an IE-only event,
   that's why it is not firing in
   Firefox. **UPDATE**: it is more complicated than this, read more here: [Javascript ondrag, ondragstart, ondragend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367055/javascript-ondrag-ondragstart-ondragend)
2. if ondragstart were available in FF, you could catch it with
   x.ondragstart=..., it works in FF
   too.
3. addEventListener is just a nicer way of assigning event handlers, it
   allows you to attach more than one
   handlers for an event to an element.
   IE has a sorf-of-equivalent called
   attachEvent.

About your problem: in non-IE browsers, to make an object unselectable, you have to catch the onmousedown event and prevent the default behavior.

Comment: 1. The event DOES fire in both cases. I put an alert into the function and it fires.
2. According to http://help.dottoro.com/ljpncnwi.php ondragstart is available in FF. But I can't use x.ondragstart= because of the XDCNativeWrapper.
3. If addEventListener is just nicer, why does replacing ".ondragstart" with ".addEventListener" exhibit different behaviors? It still fires, but doesn't override FF's default dragging like .ondragstart does.

Comment: the default behaviour can be stopped with catching mousedown

Answer (score 0):

image.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault())

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).