# Changing Page on mouse dragging event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a look the the page.

[The Link](http://www.trgms.com)

Now, what I want to do is, that when a user drags the window towards right, the windows drags to the previous page, and vice versa, which is currently being done when user clicks the right or left buttons on the screen. Can anyone please tell me any event which can tell me which way the user is dragging. With dragging, I mean, clicking the mouse, holding the click, moving the mouse and then releasing it.

Comment: may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367055/javascript-ondrag-ondragstart-ondragend

Comment: actually I dont want to drag anything, I just want the mouse gesture. Like if you click right or left button on the link I provided.

Comment: here description of set of "drags events"

http://help.dottoro.com/ljpncnwi.php

Comment: Is it ok to use jquary booklet plugin? http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/ . This is an example: http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/demos/starting

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this
http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag
this will allow you to have various drag events and methods with data like `x,y coordinates` and `deltas`

Comment: It could be useful this wasnt what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Booklet is a jquery plugin. It allow to users move through pages by dragging. If it is ok to use plugins in your application, you can use this. [page](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/)
 This is an example: [DEMO](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/demos/starting)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution worked for me. At mouseDown event I recorded mouseX and mouseY, then compared it with mouseX and mouseY that came in mouseUp event and then decided if i want to show the next tile or the previous.