# Detect if mousebutton is down on mousemove firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, mousemove

I'm trying to drag a div without having to add a mouseup function because it might bug if the user has it's mouse outside the window.

I tried using "e.which" with chrome, IE and firefox and it works fine with IE and chrome but firefox holds the last clicked button so i used e.buttons for firefox.

e.buttons worked great for the newest version but i tried using it on firefox 14 but it wasn't supported.

Do you know of an other solution?

code:

> if(!drag_enabled || drag_enabled && !e.which || e.buttons != undefined && drag_enabled && !e.buttons )
>
> return drag_enabled = false;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367055/javascript-ondrag-ondragstart-ondragend

Comment: Here is a good post for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445375/trigger-click-and-hold-event

Comment: both links need the jQuery ui to be included for the .draggable() function. I'm trying to do it without the ui

Answer (score -1):

I have faced similar problem with firefox while using e.which. So i changed my code like below which works fine in all browsers. I hope it will help you.

```
function submitOnEnter(e){ 
    if (!e) var evt = window.event;
    var charCode = e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    if(charCode == "13"){ 
        alert("Enter pressed");
    } 
}
```

and usage

```
<li onKeyDown="submitOnEnter(event)" />
```

Comment: It only registers keydowns :(
I need to check if my mousebutton is still pressed when i move it.