# Why can't I drag-and-drop a dynamically-created HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a drag and drop interface, where currently I can drag-and-drop static icons created in HTML, declared like so:

```
<img id="drag1" src="src/assets/icons/lock-locked.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="88" height="31">
```

I have written some JS to, instead, create this element:

```
var icon1 = new Image();
icon1.id="icon1"
icon1.src = "src/assets/icons/lock-locked.svg";
icon1.draggable="true";
icon1.ondragstart="drag(event)"
icon1.width="88";
icon1.height="31";
```

When inspecting the result of this in the latest version of Firefox (at time of writing), the HTML result looks like this:

```
<img id="icon1" src="src/assets/icons/lock-locked.svg" draggable="true" width="88" height="31">
```

It is missing ondragstart="drag(event)" as an attribute, and thus when I attempt to drag and drop it, with the following function:

```
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
```

data, whilst being of type 'object', is not containing the ID of the desired target (icon1) but rather the src attribute, and thus appendChild returns an error. This does not occur when the img is defined in HTML, but only when it is defined in JS.

Why can I not append the ondragstart attribute to an img defined in JS? I have tried both the following suggested methods as well:

```
object.ondragstart = function(){myScript};
object.addEventListener("dragstart", myScript);
```

and neither functions. There does not appear to be any explicable reason why the code is not doing what it claims to be doing, and yet it does not function.

EDIT: This question has been solved; I'd applied the object.addEventListener("dragstart", myScript); method incorrectly and now it works. However, StackOverflow won't let me accept the answer given in the comments and it won't let me close this question either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: `icon1.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);` is the way to do it

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding ondragstart handler to dynamically created images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296029/adding-ondragstart-handler-to-dynamically-created-images)